# ASP.NET web method custom page based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

The current project my team is working on uses webforms asp.net and are unable to at this point in development move to MVC or WebAPI.

We have started to use a WebAPI style approach using javascript client side functionality for most the page work and using webmethods for CRUD style functionality.
The issue I am having is finding a simple clean method for checking authorisation of these webmethods being called. We currently use a custom made role based security that stores a list of pages that a role has access to and on page pre init checks if the users role has access to the page and if not redirects.

My ideal solution would be to use a custom attribute like WebAPI's authorize that I could create that checks the authorisation and if fails, throws an exception and never enters the webmethod.

Is this possible, and if so how is the best way to approach?

If not has anyone else come across a similar situation that they resolved cleanly. The last thing I would like is having to add extra parameters into a webmethod just to check the authorisation.

Comment: Are you using page methods? Then you could use form authentication to verify this- http://encosia.com/asp-net-page-methods-are-only-as-secure-as-you-make-them/ hope this will help

Comment: The issue is my boss developed his own authentication system that is quite messy. On login, if authenticated it will search the database for the role that belongs to the user and obtains all the pages the authenticated has access to, then stores all of the users information and authorised pages into a created session state. On page preinit it checks if page is authorised and if not redirects. It doesn't use any of the asp.net's built in authentication api and time does not allow us to go back and change that.